# Enumeration of a list of a class which has inheritence of 2 classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable, ienumerator

I used the following code to create a class in my code enumerable:

```
public class ItemCollection : IEnumerable<AbstractItem>
{
    private List<AbstractItem> Items;

    public IEnumerator<AbstractItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

It works well, but I encountered a problem:
AbstractItem has two inheriting classes, Book and Journal, both inherit objects from AbstractItem and have some of their own (they both get "Name" from AbstractItem , but only Book has "BGenre" and only Journal has "JTopic") and because I implemented an iEnumerator of AbstractItem, I can't use the objects the inheriting classes have in a foreach loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you provide code how you want _use the objects the inheriting classes have in a foreach loop_?

Comment: you could make your collection generic: public class ItemCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : AbstractItem

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Linq* to filter out `Book`s, `Journal`s whatever:

```
ItemCollection collection = ...

var books = collection
  .OfType<Book>();

var journals = collection
  .OfType<Journal>();
```

for instance, to print out all `BGenre`s:

```
  String bGenres = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, collection
    .OfType<Book>()
    .Select(book => book.BGenre.ToString()));

  Console.Write(bGenres);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (AbstractItem item in collection)
{
    // common book and journal code here
    if (item is Book)
    {
        // some code for books
    }
    else if (item is Journal)
    {
        // some code for journals
    }
}

// another way:
List<Book> books = collection.OfType<Book>().ToList();
List<Journal> journals = collection.OfType<Journal>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics:

```
public class ItemCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> Items;

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Items.GetEnumerator();
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var books = new ItemCollection<Book>();
foreach(var book in books)
{
doSomething(book.BookProperty);
}
```

or

```
var journals = new ItemCollection<Journal>();
foreach(var journal in journals)
{
doSomething(journal.JournalProperty);
}
```

or when accessing the abstract

```
var items = new ItemCollection<AbstractItem>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
doSomething(item.AbstractItemProperty);
}
```

Comment: you can't do `var books = new ItemCollection<Book>();` because `public class ItemCollection : IEnumerable<T>` not complie

Comment: You need to define the generic variable on the class `ItemCollection<T>`

Comment: Yup, my fault, typo, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if you are doing good implementing your abstract class. but in this case you can use reflection to access to the properties of the class. like this:

```
foreach (AsbtractClass Item in ItemCollection)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo BGenre = Item.GetType().GetProperty("BGenre");
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo JTopic = Item.GetType().GetProperty("JTopic");

            if (BGenre != null) TxtResultBGenre.Text = BGenre.GetValue(Item).ToString();
            if (JTopic != null) TxtResultJTopic.Text = BGenre.GetValue(Item).ToString();
        }
```

Or you can analyze the data type of the Item and get the known property.

```
 foreach (AsbtractClass Item in ItemCollection)
            {
                if (Item is Book)
                    TxtResultBGenre.Text = System.Reflection.PropertyInfo BGenre = Item.GetType().GetProperty("BGenre").GetValue(Item).ToString();
                else if (Item is Journal)
                    TxtResultJTopic.Text = System.Reflection.PropertyInfo JTopic = Item.GetType().GetProperty("JTopic").GetValue(Item).ToString();
            }
```